# ng-click with variables in a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list of items in an ionic/angular/phonegap application and I'm trying to use an action sheet and pass in the variables. However, the ng-repeater is on an  and I don't seem to have access to the variable on the same line as the ng-repeater.

Markup:

```
<ion-view view-title="My Pets">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" ng-repeat="pet in missing" ng-click="actionSheet({{pet.AnimalCode}})">
          <img ng-src="http://*****.com/getimage.ashx?imgid={{pet.Picture}}">
          <h2>{{pet.Name}}</h2>
          <p>{{pet.Type}} - {{pet.SubType}} </p>
          <p>{{pet.Size}} - {{pet.Colour1}}</p>
          <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>  
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Backend:

```
$scope.actionSheet = function(PetID) {
            $log.info(PetID);
            var options = {
                title: 'Manage Pet',
                buttonLabels: ['Edit Pet', 'Report Lost', 'Share Pet'],
                addCancelButtonWithLabel: 'Cancel',
                androidEnableCancelButton: true,
                winphoneEnableCancelButton: true,
                addDestructiveButtonWithLabel: 'Delete Pet'
            };

            $cordovaActionSheet.show(options)
                .then(function(btnIndex) {
                    var index = btnIndex;
                });
```

PetID is empty

**EDIT - Sorry i was too quick, taking the {{}} fixed it**

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer three seconds after posting. It should be ng-click="pet.AnimalCode" not {{}}